# Why is the inverse of the standard charts on $\mathbb{R}P^n$ continuous?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

When showing that $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is a topological manifold, the atlas is given by charts $\varphi_i\colon U_i\to\mathbb{R}^n$, where the $U_i$ are the classes $[x^1,\dots,x^{n+1}]$ with $x_i\neq 0$, and the coordinate charts are defined by
$$
\varphi_i[x^1,\dots,x^{n+1}]=\left(\frac{x^1}{x^i},\dots,\frac{x^{i-1}}{x^i},\frac{x^{i+1}}{x^i},\dots,\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^i}\right)
$$
and
$$
\varphi_i^{-1}(u^1,\dots,u^n)=[u^1,\dots,u^{i-1},1,u^i,\cdots,u^n].
$$

But why is $\varphi_i^{-1}$ is continuous?

I can't get a good grasp on what an open sets in $\Bbb RP^n$ look like. I look at them by taking their representatives in $\Bbb R^{n+1}\setminus 0$, and then I know the set is open if all the lines through those representatives, minus $0$, which looks like two cones missing their vertex is open in $\Bbb R^{n+1}\setminus 0$, but it's proving difficult to show the preimage of an open set is open under $\varphi_i^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb{R}P^n$ is (usually) equipped with the quotient topology induced by

$$
\psi : \Bbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \to \Bbb{R}P^n, x \mapsto [x_1, \dots, x_{n+1}].
$$

In particular, $\psi$ is continuous. Why is that helpful?

Additional question: why is $U_i$ an open set?

Comment: $U_i$ is open since $\pi^{-1}(U_i)$ is the set of points in $R^{n+1}\setminus 0$ with nonzero $i$th coordinate, which is open as the complement of the closed set given by the affine subspace $x_i=0$?

Comment: What I let $f_i\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus 0$ by $f_i(u_1,\dots,u_n)=(u_1,\dots,u_{i-1},1,u_{i+1},\dots,u_n)$. Then $\varphi_i^{-1}=\psi\circ f_i$, so is continuous as the composition of continuous maps?

Comment: Yes and yes (if you mean $\pi = \psi$ in the first comment).